# Laravel Provider Configuration

Tags: service, laravel, configuration, environment, provider

Start working with Laravel Environment Configuration I want to override the base database.php. So I have another database.php file in app/config/local/ directory. Now I want to "append" environment service providers to my primary app configuration file. Following the Laravel docs I need to call the append_config helper method in the app/config/local/app.php file with the following.

```
'providers' => append_config(array(
    'LocalOnlyServiceProvider',
))
```

Did I call this append_config method in the right file? This method accepts an array as argument. What should be the right value of this array?

Answer (score 1):

An quick example how I added a Service Provider in my /app/config/local/app.php file. If you want to add another service, just add another item in the array.

```
'providers' => append_config(
    array('Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider')
),
```

Comment: do you add this code in /app/config/local/app.php file?

Comment: Yes I do. I add it in my /app/config/local/app.php file.

Comment: you used 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' as the array value. How do I know what array value I need to use?

Comment: It's depends on which service provider you want to add. If you start a new project and you don't have any Service Provider to add, just forget this configuration part.